# JSON elements being displayed twice after call

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, getjson, each

Im having some trouble displaying some JSON objects. If the object is displayed using `$.each()` then it will display on screen twice. If I dont use `$.each()` to display the object then it displays once. The example shows below that the ruler content will be loaded twice, but the text content will only be loaded in once.

The JSON file is only called once. I checked this up using Firebug.

Im using jQuery 1.8.0 and using the history.js plugin

The JSON file validates using jsonlint.com.

I need to find out why the elements are being displayed twice. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

The code:

```
function JSONLoader(page)
{
    //The page is "about" page then..
    if(page == 'about')
    {

        $.getJSON('about.json', function(data, textStatus){
            var htmlRuler="";
            $.each(data.person, function(pageIndex, page){  

                //The ruler content will load in twice
                if(page.RulerDiv){
                    htmlRuler += '<ul>';
                    $.each(page.RulerDiv,function(rulerIndex, ruler){
                        htmlRuler += '<li><img class="'+ruler.imgClass+'" src="'+ruler.imgURI+'" alt="'+ruler.imgAlt+'" title="'+ruler.imgTitle+'"/></li>';                         
                    });
                    htmlRuler += '</ul>';
                }                       
                $('.RulerDiv').append(htmlRuler).fadeIn('slow');

                //This loads the text in once only.
                if(page.TextDiv){
                    var htmltext = '<p class="' + page.TextDiv.textClass+'">'+ page.TextDiv.Text + '</p>';      
                }
                $('.TextDiv').append(htmltext).fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Some sample JSON for this. The array RulerDiv would be implemented twice.

```
{
"person": {
    "page": {
        "RulerDiv": [
                {
                    "imgURI": "../img/rulerButton.png",
                    "imgTitle": "",
                    "imgClass": "hover whoRulerDivImg",
                    "imgAlt" : ""
                },
                {
                    "imgURI": "../img/rulerButton2.png",
                    "imgTitle": "",
                    "imgClass": "hover RulerDivImg",
                    "imgAlt" : ""
                }
            ],
        "TextDiv": {
            "wText" : "He is alive",
            "textClass" : "fontClass"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post a sample of the JSON string so we can see what you are iterating through? Also, i suggest upgrading to 1.8.2, it fixes several bugs found in 1.8.0 (such as IE9 firing .ready too early). It most likely won't affect your current problem though.

Comment: Where is `htmlRuler` defined?

Comment: Do you initialize or reset `htmlRuler` anywhere? The way it looks right now is that you always append text to htmlRuler on each getJSON call, then you append everything to .RulerDiv. Again without resetting .RulerDiv anywhere.

Comment: Sorry I left that out, `var htmlRuler="";` is defined just after `$.getJSON`. Ill add some sample JSON now.

Comment: @Andy Should I have to reset ".RulerDiv". I want the elements to remain on screen, so im unsure why you would reset it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*FIXED*

The problem was that I was iterating over the data twice. Taking out the first `.each()` and changing the code to the code below fixes this bug.

```
$.getJSON('about.json', function(data, textStatus){
            var htmlRuler="";  

            if(data.person.page.RulerDiv){
                htmlRuler += '<ul>';
                $.each(data.person.page.RulerDiv,function(rulerIndex, ruler){
                    htmlRuler += '<li><img class="'+ruler.imgClass+'" src="'+ruler.imgURI+'" alt="'+ruler.imgAlt+'" title="'+ruler.imgTitle+'"/></li>';                         
                });
                htmlRuler += '</ul>';
            }                       
            $('.RulerDiv').append(htmlRuler).fadeIn('slow');
```

Answer (score 4):

Try changing your following code:

```
if(page.RulerDiv){
   htmlRuler += '<ul>';
```

for this one:

```
htmlRuler = '';
if(page.RulerDiv){
   htmlRuler += '<ul>';
```

because it seems to me you are appending to the same variable `htmlRuler` inside the `.each()` loop without clearing the contents from your previous iteration.

Comment: I left that out of the code above, and Ive put it back into it. That wasn't the issue unfortunately. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try to change your code with this one. It does looks good for me.

```
$.each(data.person, function(pageIndex, page){  
   // try to change these only and see        
    var htmlRuler = "";
             if(page.RulerDiv){
                htmlRuler = $('<ul>').clone();
                $.each(page.RulerDiv,function(rulerIndex, ruler){
                    var imgDom = $('<img>').clone(); 
                var liDom = $('<li>').clone();
                    $('<img>').addClass(ruler.imgClass).attr({'src':ruler.imgURI,'alt':ruler.imgAlt,'title':ruler.imgTitle})
                              .appendTo($('<li>').appendTo(htmlRuler));
                });
            }                       
            $('.RulerDiv').append(htmlRuler).fadeIn('slow');

            //This loads the text in once only.
            if(page.TextDiv){
                var htmltext = '<p class="' + page.TextDiv.textClass+'">'+ page.TextDiv.Text + '</p>';      
            }
            $('.TextDiv').append(htmltext).fadeIn('slow');
        });
```